# bypass firewall with Openvpn + Squid

Tags: openvpn, squid

I have 2 VPS servers, one in China and another in the US. The server (openvpn client) in China is connected to the US one via openvpn. I also have squid running in the China server. I want to redirect all traffic to squid through the openvpn tunnel to the US server. (so users can access blocked sites including youtube.com, facebook, twitter and the likes). I currently have all outgoing http and https traffic on the China server going through the openvpn tunnel. I verify this because when visiting normal sites, the public ip address has already become the US ip address. Yet I still cannot access blocked sites due to DNS pollution, and all these sites resolve to the unreachable ip address. How can I circumvent the DNS pollution issue in this case? I know there are other ways to bypass the gfw (e.g., SSH tunnel, VPN) but this method is the most convenient one for ordinary users.

Answer (score 0):

If the DNS is still being polluted then presumably the clients are using their original DNS server configuration.

You can push new DNS server information to the clients from the OpenVPN server as part of the client setup

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
```

There is more about push dhcp-options an in the documentation. You could even consider setting up your own caching DNS server and have your clients use it.

You are making the VPN the default route for the clients aren't you ?

Comment: Thanks. i've already added this option in the server config. but it doesn't help!